# Priority in Static routes?

Tags: networking, routing, solaris, priority

I have 2 default routes with different gateways:

```
# netstat -nr

Routing Table: IPv4
  Destination           Gateway           Flags  Ref     Use     Interface
-------------------- -------------------- ----- ----- ---------- ---------
default              10.150.19.65         UG        1       3217

default              10.150.16.66         UG        1         47
```

How can i make the server to take 16.66 as a prior on 19.65?
second thing, i am trying to find system file that contains static routes.

Knowing that:

```
# more /etc/release
                    Oracle Solaris 10 8/11 s10x_u10wos_17b X86
  Copyright (c) 1983, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
                            Assembled 23 August 2011
```

Comment: short answer is you can't have 2 default gateway in unix world, justdelete 10.10.19.65, (or use dynamic routing like `gated` if you like gambling)

Answer (score 0):

Unix usually don't allow two default gateway (mainly because there si no way for kernel to know which to use)

Delete current route using

```
route delete default 10.150.19.65
```

This won't survive a reboot, next step is to edit `/etc/gatways`.

As per http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-configuring-solaris-unix-static-routes/